# RGBApixel memory issue with EasyBMP c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have the following line in my main() function (which uses EasyBMP):

```
RGBApixel * myPixel = myFavoriteColor(192);
```

which is defined as:

```
RGBApixel * myFavoriteColor(int intensity)
{
RGBApixel color;
color.Red   = 0;
color.Green = intensity/2;
color.Blue  = intensity;
return &color;
}
```

and I'm getting the following error on a line that says "delete myPixel": malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbff9d0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Why is it not getting allocated correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the address of the local variable `color` which will not be valid after exiting the function `myFavoriteColor`. The object `color` will be destroyed at the end of the function. Instead return a copy the object `RGBAPixel` by chnaging the function signature to `RGBAPixel myFavoriteColor(int)` and using `return color;`

**EDIT**

You need to change `RGBApixel * myPixel = myFavoriteColor(192);` to `RGBApixel myPixel = myFavoriteColor(192);` as well. I believe you should read a [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before going further as these are very basic concepts.

Comment: That leads to: main.cpp:28: error: cannot convert ‘RGBApixel’ to ‘RGBApixel*’ in initialization

Comment: Yeah, I know they're simple. I'm just beginning to learn. Is it at all possible to keep the RGBApixel's as pointers?

Comment: It is possible to return `RGBApixel *` from the function. In that case you need to allocate memory for `color` usng `new RGBApixel();`. In this case memory will be allocated from heap and the object will still be valid outside the function. However, remember that you need to release the memory explictly using `delete myPixel;` (from main) in such case. To avoid this manual memory management you can use what is called a smart pointer such as `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Then I would do: RGBApixel * myFavoriteColor(int intensity)
{
    RGBApixel * color = new RGBApixel();
    color->Red   = 0;
    color->Green = intensity/2;
    color->Blue  = intensity;
    return color;
}
??